# Is it possible to execute a script as first at shutdown/reboot on Debian?

Tags: debian, shutdown, bash-script, reboot, init.d

I am currently trying to register a script *(located in the /etc/init.d)* in a way that makes this script being executed as the first script/programm at shutdown/reboot *(change to running level 0 or 6)*.

I used `update-rc.d stop_servers stop 0 0 6 .` to register the script for these two runlevels. It is correctly registered there but has the name `K01stop_servers`. This makes the script not being executed as the first one.
I basically need everything still running. That's why I want it to be the first.
Namely I still need my apache, mysql and (s)ftp servers running and my java still fully functional.

How do I achieve this?

The script goes as follows:

```
#! /bin/bash

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          mc_server_safe_shutdown
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:
# Default-Stop:      0 6
# Description:       Shuts down all Minecraft serves softly
### END INIT INFO

/root/.stop_servers

exit 0
```

Comment: Any reason you cannot use the regular services infrastructure to start and stop the Minecraft servers? Then you can list any dependencies they have, and update-rc.d should take care of the interdependencies.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. And I really don't know the names of these services. That would help me very much.

Comment: Well, the `Required-Start` and `Required-Stop` parts should be easy to take from the relevant service scripts. And you can use any other service script as a template. Have a look at e.g. /etc/init.d/motd for a simple service script that should be available on almost any Debian installation. Also note that the only difference between `K` and `S` links is (1) the parameter they get invoked with (`stop` vs `start`) and (2) whether they get invoked when entering (`S`) or leaving (`K`) *the runlevel*.

Comment: You thing this should work ``# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog $apache2 $mysql``?

Comment: I think you should have a look at `man 8 insserv`; it should tell you what those comments actually stand for. For a start, `$` or no `$` before a literal is significant.

Comment: It worked with ``# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog apache2 mysql``. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do what you want to do is to **make a custom init script that lists the necessary dependencies. Within that script, you start/stop the service in question,** depending on whether the script is called with `start` or `stop` as the first parameter.

You can start with a simple script such as `/etc/init.d/motd` as a template, as it will have all the basic parts to make it all work at all. In your case, you want the script to state

```
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog apache2 mysql
```

because you need the `remote_fs` and `syslog` *facilities* running (but you don't care what exact service provides those facilities), and specifically the `apache2` and `mysql` *services* running, at the time the stop action is issued. Note that Java isn't a service per se, but using it may have dependencies on services, including file systems.

`Should-Stop` and `Required-Stop` are described in the insserv(8) man page as:

> In both cases the script system should avoid stopping services which are declared by these two `Stop` tags until the script including these tags is stopped.

The names are from `Provides` (literal service names, no `$` sign at the beginning) of service init scripts, and from `/etc/insserv.conf` (facility names, `$` sign at the beginning).

When you have the script the way you want it, install it using `update-rc.d` or directly using `insserv`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to execute a script only at shutdown, you don't need:

```
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
```

You can leave this empty.

Each script has `Provides` entry which defines names of other scripts that you can use in the `Required-Start` and `Required-Stop` directives. The order is reversed in the two fields. If something has to start before the script, you have to put it into `Required-Start` directive. But if the script has to stop before a certain service, the name of that service has to be placed in `Required-Stop`.

So, in your example you want to run the script before apache and mysql termination at shutdown. All you have to do is to check the `Provides` directive in appropriate init files.

```
$ cat /etc/init.d/apache2
...
# Provides:          apache2
...
```

and:

```
$ cat /etc/init.d/mysql
...
# Provides:          mysql
...
```

Now you just add `apache2` and `mysql` to your script under the `Required-Stop` directive:

```
# Required-Stop: apache2 mysql
```

You can read more about the header of an init script [here](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts) . There's also some info concerning facility names, for example the mentioned `$remote_fs`and `$syslog`:

> $local_fs -- all local filesystems are mounted. All scripts that write
>   in /var/ need to depend on this, unless they already depend on
>   $remote_fs.
>
> $network -- low level networking (ethernet card; may imply PCMCIA
>   running)
>
> $named -- daemons which may provide hostname resolution (if present)
>   are running. For example, daemons to query DNS, NIS+, or LDAP.
>
> $portmap -- daemons providing SunRPC/ONCRPC portmapping service as
>   defined in RFC 1833 (if present) are running all remote
>
> $remote_fs -- all filesystems are mounted. In some LSB run-time
>   environments, filesystems such as /usr may be remote. If the script
>   need a mounted /usr/, it needs to depend on $remote_fs. Scripts
>   depending on $remote_fs do not need to depend on $local_fs. During
>   shutdown, scripts that need to run before sendsigs kills all processes
>   should depend on $remote_fs.
>
> $syslog -- system logger is operational
>
> $time -- the system time has been set, for example by using a
>   network-based time program such as ntp or rdate, or via the hardware
>   Real Time Clock. Note that just depending on ntp will not result in an
>   accurate time just after ntp started. It usually takes minutes until
>   ntp actually adjusts the time. Also note that standard insserv.conf
>   just lists hwclock as $time.
>
> $all -- facility supported by insserv to start a script after all the
>   other scripts, at the end of the boot sequence. This only work for
>   start ordering, not stop ordering. It is not possible to depend on a
>   script which depend on $all.

After you change a header in an init script, you have to run `update-rc.d` and it will set the right order of all scripts based on their headers:

```
# update-rc.d script defaults
```

Comment: I like your answer more but I promissed the other guy.